# Seperate task in different request will be faster in PHP?

Tags: php

Say I received a request to perform 5 task. Which will be faster?

1. Do all 5 tasks in this request.
2. Send 5 more HTTP request to do the 5 tasks seperately. (I am not sure if sending HTTP quest in PHP is good. But I don't know how to do them locally and I need to write code in my framework)

Extra information : I am doing a timed task system. Tasks will be stored in DB, and I will have someone trigger the main controller every minute to perform the on-time task.

Extra demand : If you have suggestion on the design, I am happy to get enlightened!

Comment: It depends, but in general if each task can be done separately (no dependency), you could perform them in the separated requests.

Comment: @TuanDuong. Will it have very good impact or just so-so? Because to do them in one request will be easier for me.

Comment: It belongs to your application. Basically HTTP is stateless protocol then it's hard to connect requests together. In case you need to add dependency to the tasks later (or it adds automatically), the problem will be more complex. Are tasks heavy and take time to perform?

Comment: @TuanDuong. The tasks are heavy but have no dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tasks are heavy and no dependency, cronjob is a good solution for you as first. You may setup cronjob which runs every minute, and call PHP script to perform the task. You may need to log the status into file/db to monitor.

You also may need a status flag to make sure the tasks are not overlapped in performing.

If you are looking for more trustable and "enterprise" solutions, you can check queue technology (RabbitMQ or Gearman...).

For the quick solution, HTTP request for 5 tasks is still good, but you have to manage status carefully (apply transaction...)

Comment: I need the tools provided by the framework, I just can't write dependent .php file, that is why I need to handle it the HTTP way.

Comment: @bijiDango Which framework do you use? Most frameworks provide CLI tool which executes PHP script in CLI mode (with benefit of the framework of course)